# Quick-cooking vs. regular oats for bread

Tags: bread, oats

I've got a bread-machine recipe for oatmeal bread that calls for either quick-cooking oats or regular oats.  Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: Regular meaning steel cut? I'd think uncooked whole oat groats would just sit there and look at you funny if you put them in a bread recipe; end up crunchier than added roast sunflower seeds.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger : 'regular' in the U.S. being rolled oats.  Groats are pretty uncommon over here.  (they're often sold as 'pinhead oats', 'steel cut oats' or 'Irish oatmeal')

Answer (score 3):

'Quick cooking' (aka 'instant') oats have been cooked more, and are in smaller pieces than regular (aka. 'old fashioned', aka. 'rolled' oats).

- If you'd prefer more texture in the bread, go with the old fashioned oats.
- If you're trying to make them less noticable, go with the quick cooking oats.
- If you only have one on hand, go with whatever it is that you already have.

Comment: According to [this question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3909/difference-between-old-fashioned-and-quick-oats) instant oats are not the same thing as quick-cooking oats, and cannot be substituted for them.

Comment: I'd add that if you prefer less "texture" and only have "old fashioned oats," you can always soak the oats in some of the recipe's liquid for a few hours before mixing with the rest.  If soaked beforehand, even the "old fashioned" rolled oats will blend in a lot more.