# Recipe calls for rolled oats, I have old fashioned oats - can I substitute them in cookies?

Tags: substitutions, oats

Can old fashioned oats be used when a cookie recipe calls for rolled oats?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between old fashioned and quick oats?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3909/difference-between-old-fashioned-and-quick-oats)

Comment: @senschen This is not a dupe... "Quick Oats" are not the same thing as "rolled oats".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Old Fashioned Oats and Rolled Oats are two names for the same thing. To wit: "Rolled oats are traditionally oat groats that have been dehusked and steamed, before being rolled into flat flakes under heavy rollers and stabilized by being lightly toasted." (from Wikipedia)